# how to close dialog fragment properly

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialogfragment, dismiss

I tried two solutions to close fragment, but none of these worked for me.
first solution:-

```
binding.closeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }
```

When I close my dialog back side is fully blank for this solution.

Second solution:-

```
close_btn.setOnClickListener {
            requireActivity().onBackPressed()
        }
```

When I close my dialog my full app get closed.

Can you please help me to solve my problem

```
 class CongratulationsDialog : DialogFragment() {
    lateinit var bid :String
    lateinit var sharedPreference: SharedPreference
    var mLogoProgressDialog: ProgressDialog? = null
    var text : String = ""
    var uid :String = ""
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate<CongratulationsDialogBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.congratulations_dialog,
            container,
            false)
        dialog?.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog?.setContentView(R.layout.congratulations_dialog)
        dialog?.window?.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

        sharedPreference = activity?.let { SharedPreference(it) }!!
        bid = sharedPreference.getValueString("sendBid").toString()
        text = sharedPreference.getValueString("token").toString()
        uid = sharedPreference.getValueString("login_uid").toString()
        Log.d("checkLoginId",""+uid+"Bid"+bid)
        initializeLogoProgressDialog()
        loadBettingStatus(bid,text,binding)

        binding.closeBtn.setOnClickListener {
            dismiss()
        }
        binding.createNewBoastButton.setOnClickListener {
            view?.let { it1 ->
                Navigation.findNavController(it1)
                    .navigate(R.id.action_congratulationsDialog_to_newBoastFragment)
            }
        }
        return binding.root
    }

    private fun initializeLogoProgressDialog() {
        if (mLogoProgressDialog == null) {
            Log.w("PBFX", "initializeLogoProgressDialog called - mLogoProgressDialog = NULL")
        } else {
            Log.w("PBFX", "initializeLogoProgressDialog called - mLogoProgressDialog NOT NULL")
        }
        if (mLogoProgressDialog == null) {
            dismissLogoProgressDialog()
            mLogoProgressDialog = ProgressDialog(requireContext())
            mLogoProgressDialog!!.show()
            mLogoProgressDialog!!.setCancelable(false)
            mLogoProgressDialog!!.getWindow()!!
                .setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
            mLogoProgressDialog!!.setContentView(R.layout.progress_bar)
        }
    }

    private fun loadBettingStatus(bid: String, text: String, binding: CongratulationsDialogBinding) {
        val apiInterface = RetrofitService.api.getInviteesDetails(bid,"Bearer "+text)

        apiInterface.enqueue( object : Callback<Invitees> {
            override fun onResponse(call: Call<Invitees>?, response: Response<Invitees>) {
                if (response.isSuccessful) {
                    dismissLogoProgressDialog()
                    if (response?.body() != null) {
                        if(response.body()!!.data.status.equals("completed")) {
                            binding.textView7.text =response.body()!!.data.name
                            if (uid.equals(response.body()!!.data.betWinner.uid)) {
                                binding.youTxt.setText("You")
                                if(response.body()!!.data.mode.equals("task")){
                                    binding.textView10.setText(response.body()!!.data.taskTitle)
                                }else{
                                    binding.textView10.setText("$"+response.body()!!.data.value)
                                }
                            } else {
                                dismissLogoProgressDialog()
                                binding.youTxt.setText(response.body()!!.data.betWinner.name)
                                if(response.body()!!.data.mode.equals("task")){
                                    binding.textView10.setText(response.body()!!.data.taskTitle)
                                }else{
                                    binding.textView10.setText("$"+response.body()!!.data.value)
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }else{
                    dismissLogoProgressDialog()
                }
            }
            override fun onFailure(call: Call<Invitees>?, t: Throwable?) {
                if (t != null) {
                    dismissLogoProgressDialog()
                    Log.d("gettingFailure",""+t.message)
                }
            }
        })
    }

    private fun dismissLogoProgressDialog() {
        if (mLogoProgressDialog != null) {
            mLogoProgressDialog!!.dismiss()
        }
        mLogoProgressDialog = null
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
       // close_btn.setOnClickListener {
       //     requireActivity().onBackPressed()
       // }
    }
    override fun getTheme() = R.style.RoundedCornersDialog
}
```

Comment: `dismiss()` is the correct way. "back side is fully blank for this solution" What does this mean?

Comment: after close that congratulations dialog it goes to my home fragment, that page is fully empty I can't able to see any data in that page

Comment: `dismiss()` is enough for this . for data lost you need to debug the lifecycle stuff on Home fragment . pls add code with question how and where r you opening the DialogFragment .

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to close dialog this.

```
Fragment frag = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment_dialog");
if (frag != null) {
    DialogFragment df = (DialogFragment) frag;
    df.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: What is `prev`?

Comment: Hey sorry just now i edited content please check it now

Comment: You can use typealias if you want to close this dialog fragment from another fragment. (Kotlin only)

Comment: I don't think this solves the OP problem since this is the same as doing dismiss() inside the dialog instance.

Comment: What do you mean "you can use typealias"?